# not find artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:

Tags: mysql, grails

i'm trying to connect grails to mysql but i get this error:

```
| Loading Grails 2.4.4 | Error There was an error loading the
BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates mys
ql:mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin, expected format is
<groupId>:<artifactId>[:< extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version(Use
--stacktrace to see the full trace)

| Configuring classpath | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies:
Could not find artifact mysql:mysq l-connector-java:jar:5.1.23-bin in
grailsCentral (htts://repo.grails.org/grails /plugins) (Use
--stacktrace to see the full trace) | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact mysql:mysq
l-connector-java:jar:5.1.23-bin in grailsCentral
(htts://repo.grails.org/grails /plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the
full trace) | Error Could not find artifact
mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.23-bin in gra ilsCentral
(htts://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) | Run 'grails
dependency-report' for further information.
```

how can i fix this error ?
here is my buidconfig:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0) grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level =1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256] ]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "htt://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "htt://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "htt://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.23-bin'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

and datasource:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"
    username = "root"
    password = "thanh" } hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false //    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context }

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/bkavr"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/bkav"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/bkav"
            properties {
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.23-bin'`

to

`runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'`

That should pull in the dependency correctly.

Comment: thanks jeff beck. when i change and run it have this error: | Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates mys
ql:mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin, expected format is <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<
extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version> (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
can you help me fix this ?

Comment: You shouldn't still have anything in build config that has 5.1.23-bin do you?